# Warning in Stanford Tagger.php Warning: proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 0

Tags: php, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford namespace But having this warning in Stanford Tagger.php

> Warning: proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 0

it's caused by this line

```
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, dirname($this->getJar()));
```

I can't know how to resolve it.

Comment: I have the same issue here on my end

Comment: What is there in your $cmd?

Comment: Check this http://readlist.com/lists/lists.php.net/php-windows/0/798.html

Comment: Your question cannot be answered because you haven't given us enough details. What machine is this running on? What PHP version? And most importantly: What are the arguments of `proc_open()`? Have you read the notes on this page? http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the example in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and I was getting the exact same error as well (I am on windows using WAMP).

After some digging around, I found that I can fix the problem by omitting out the dir and env params, for example - this works for me:

```
<?php

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = 'D:/wamp/www/test';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, /* $cwd, $env */ );

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}

?>
```

So, can you try updating your code from:

```
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, dirname($this->getJar()));
```

To:

```
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

---

If this works for you, then the problem is with this line `dirname($this->getJar())` of your code. Either this path does not exists or the it's not accessible.

Have you do a `var_dump()` of `dirname($this->getJar())` and check if that path exists?

---

The above example was fixed by setting current working dir like this also:

```
$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, getcwd(), $env );
```

According to documentation:

> cwd
>
> The initial working dir for the command. This must be an absolute directory path, or
>   NULL if you want to use the default value (the working dir of the current PHP process)

Comment: Thank you for this @latheesan, I knew there was something simple off but couldn't spot it.